# How to change a dynamic <select> value based on URL parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to change selected option based on URL parameters:
`http://localhost/ncapro/new%20folder/home.php?select=Work%20From%20Home`
from above example I want to change the default selected option to value of *select* which is **Work From Home**
So, this is what I am currently doing to achieve it:

```
<select id="catagOption" class="category">
      <option selected>All</option>
      Other options are dynamic and are loaded via javascript... All options have a specific value...
</select>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function selectFromURL(){
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const product = urlParams.get('select');
    let s = product.replaceAll(/\s/g, '');
    $('#catagOption').val(product);
    $(".Detect").fadeOut();
    $(`.${s}`).fadeIn();
}
$(function(){
selectFromURL();
});
```

And this is how I have made the select dynamic:

```
$.getJSON("string.json", function(data){
let $gString = data.gString
let result = $gString.map(a => a.catag)
let unik = [...new Set(result)]
unik.forEach(e => {
        $(`<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`).appendTo('.category')
    })
})
```

but this doesn't works and doesn't give me results what I am expecting. However when executing this function in console or executing it after some delay, it works the way I want it to. So, what is the problem and how should I deal with it?

Comment: Works perfectly fine here (when I replace accessing the query string, which can't easily be manipulated in a fiddle, with a static string) - https://jsfiddle.net/2kjt8c3r/ And since this is wrapped in a document ready handler there is no apparent reason, why this should not work on page load, but later on when executed via console - unless your select field was loaded dynamically itself, or something? This needs an example that actually shows the problem.

Comment: Yeah my select is actually a dynamic select, so, what should I do

Comment: Call `selectFromURL()` in the `$.getJSON` callback instead of the document.ready handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Your tip worked, thank you very very much